# Get an element's XPath after locating it through ClassName

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to get an element's XPath after locating it through ClassName.

```
while (driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("N_elemt")).Count() > 0) 
{ 
var result = driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("N_element")); 
result = XPath of N_element ; 
Console.WriteLine(result);  

}
```

I am using a C# project.  
Thanks!

Comment: Since you use findElement, the size of the result is equal to 1. First, try to get the name of the element with : `temp = driver.findElement(By.xpath("name(//*[@class="N_elemt"][1])"))` Then concat the result (i don't use C#) : concat '//' & temp & '[@class="N_elemt"]' to generate the XPath.